# bonding multiple proxy connection

Tags: proxy, nginx, load-balancing, haproxy

I want to use multiple proxy servers at the same time to speed my downloads. Reverse proxy products such as haproxy and nginx can use multiple proxy servers, but only one proxy per session.

Client---haproxy---proxy1/proxy2/proxy3-----Webserver

But I want to balance one session. Imagine that I am downloading big file. In normal conditions this download comes to client through only one proxy. But I want to divide this download into 3 parts and utilize 3 proxies.